# Angular10 Reactive Form validation both on blur and submit

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I'm trying to validate the form on blur and every time the submit button is being pressed, however there is no option as:

```
updateOn: ['blur', 'submit']
```

It is either `updateOn: 'blur'` or `updateOn: 'submit'`

Is there a way or workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is workaround for you :)

[How to validate form on submit](https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-reactive-forms-trigger-validation-on-submit/#validating-all-fields-on-submit)

Depending on your form structure you have to iterate on every field and mark it as touched.

For flat from group it should be enough

```
Object.keys(form).forEach(field => {
  const control = form.get(field); 
  control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
});
```

Of course you have execute that code in you onSubmit method